# application development

Tags: java

I am developing an application. How can I implement open and save operations? It would require connecting to the user's file system. Any sample code in this regard?

Comment: do yourself a favor, buy a book :)

Comment: Your question is vague please elaborate.

Comment: Please supply enormous amounts of additional detail.

Comment: And while you're at it, change your title, it's not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to have a look at Suns tutorial  [Reading, Writing, and Creating Files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) or alternatively java [serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).

Answer (score 1):

Still I can give you some guidelines.

1. You need to decide what technologies you want to use to build application like Java Swing or some other web related technologies.
2. If you are going for Java Swing then there are components which allow to save or open file with no interaction with file system. Please go through this [FileChooser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)